# How I can open back door for myself?

Tags: security

I hired a developer to edit a specific plugin in my website.
As we all know he can't edit the code of that plugin without giving him key-master/administration permeation.

He can at any time to delete my account and take the whole control of my website, I made a plan B and made a backup for my whole website, If anything goes wrong I will delete my whole website from cpanel and make a setup from the backup.

My question is: How I can make myself un-deletable, or made a second door for myself to access my website if he decide to delete my account?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with wordpress.com so I removed the tag. wordpress.com is a hosted service

Comment: I would also strongly advise against editing plugins via the built in editor, a single typo and the whole site could go down because of a syntax error

Comment: @narzan Use an isolated test/local install for developing the plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course,someone can editing code plugins via the editor and build the shell or somethings like that but I don't they can able to hack your database. Just simple, you can permit developer with specific user role. But I think the best way is using an isolated local install for developing the plugin: xampp,etc...

Comment: Is it possible to isolate a key-master from deleting an account?

Comment: Not sure. but I think you can make plugin to prevent delete account through user_id default 1 and prevent edit this plugin on server with unix permission! No one can delete your account and edit this plugin if he can't get access to your server lol .I don't keymaster role in default wordpress but bbpress has it.
Of course if I developed the website and wanna freelancer or developer make specific plugin. I think git, maven,svn or simliar tools like that, they permit you can manage developer, see fixed code.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide the developer access to your database, you will always be able to create a new admin-user directly in the **wp_users** table.

So basically you can use the database as a backdoor.